# Number formatting using php

Tags: php, string-formatting

I am using php. I want to display a number in a '$XX.XXX.XX' format. I tried the following code, but its not giving full output.

```
<?php echo "$".number_format(round($customer['hourly_payment']),2); ?>
Output
 $17,317.00
```

Please suggest a solution!

Comment: And what would be the expected output? [RTM](http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php) Where is the problem ?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you missed the following function's last 2 parameters:

> string number_format ( float $number , int $decimals = 0 , string
> $dec_point = "." , string $thousands_sep = "," )

For your case:

```
number_format($number, 2, '.', '.');
```

Read more: https://www.php.net/number_format

Answer (score 0):

Try with -

```
echo number_format(100000000, 2, '.', '.');
```

**Output**

```
100.000.000.00
```